# How do I connect my Xbox 360 controller to my 2.4Ghz wireless gaming receiver if it doesn't have a connect button?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

How do I connect my Xbox 360 controller to my 2.4Ghz wireless gaming receiver if it doesn't have a connect button?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, what does this have to do with Steam? Can you tell us what model of wireless receiver you have?

Comment: It only says 2.4g wireless gaming receiver on it

Comment: We definitely need more details.  Can you link to Amazon or some other retailer/manufacturer of the receiver? That may help.  How are you planning on using this as well? Like Controller → receiver → PC?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter whatever the "receiver" questioner uses, unless it's official USB dongle which is now EoL.

Xbox 360 controller does *not* have Bluetooth connectivity or any of the normal connectivity, instead it uses proprietary RF(radio frequency) interface. Bluetooth connectivity is only available for Xbox One controller and newer.

Just in case, some sources:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_360_controller)(states that it uses proprietary 2.4 GHz protocol)
[Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1199466/how-to-connect-xbox-360-controller-to-pc-with-only-bluetooth)

And just in case if questioner is using official USB dongle:

[Microsoft webpage](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/xbox-360/xbox-on-windows/accessories/xbox-controller-for-windows-setup)